# Does MONO WCF support Azure Service bus Relay

Tags: linux, azure, mono, azureservicebus

I currently designing a solution for communication between a Charge Point for Electrical Vehicles and the backoffice. the ChargePoint are connected to the Network of the Telephone company and the backoffice is hosted on Azure. The Chargepoint don't have a public IP-address. In order to send messagese from the backoffice to the ChargePoint we want to implement Azure Service Bus (ASB) Relay. The ChargePoint OS is embeded Linux and Azure is Microsoft. The ASB Relay only works with WCF bindings. I found out that mono supports WCF but cann't find if it supports httpRelayBinding?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of communication are you looking for between the device and service? If you need Relay like two-way or one-way synchronous RPC communication then you could use a simple http client to call into the service, a sample for this is here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Relayed-Messaging-Bindings-a6477ba0

Also if you are looking for different patterns of communication such a brokered messaging where you can send/receive messages w/ data then you can consider using Service Bus Queues and Topics. I recently covered some of these usage scenarios in my session at TechEd: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/WAD-B336